# Google Mock: Return() a list of values

Tags: c++, return-value, googlemock

Via Google Mock's Return() you can return what value will be returned once a mocked function is called. However, if a certain function is expected to be called many times, and each time you would like it to return a different predefined value.

For example:

```
EXPECT_CALL(mocked_object, aCertainFunction (_,_))
    .Times(200);
```

How do you make `aCertainFunction` each time return an incrementing integer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [sequences](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CheatSheet.md#sequences):

```
using ::testing::Sequence;

Sequence s1;
for (int i=1; i<=20; i++) {
    EXPECT_CALL(mocked_object, aCertainFunction (_,_))
        .InSequence(s1)
        .WillOnce(Return(i));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use functors, as explained [here](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CookBook#Using_Functions/Methods/Functors_as_Actions).

---

Something like this :

```
int aCertainFunction( float, int );

struct Funct
{
  Funct() : i(0){}

  int mockFunc( float, int )
  {
    return i++;
  }
  int i;
};

// in the test
Funct functor;
EXPECT_CALL(mocked_object, aCertainFunction (_,_))
    .WillRepeatedly( Invoke( &functor, &Funct::mockFunc ) )
    .Times( 200 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You might like this solution, which hides implementation details in the mock class.

In the mock class, add:

```
using testing::_;
using testing::Return;

ACTION_P(IncrementAndReturnPointee, p) { return (*p)++; }

class MockObject: public Object {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD(...)
    ...

    void useAutoIncrement(int initial_ret_value) {    
        ret_value = initial_ret_value - 1;

        ON_CALL(*this, aCertainFunction (_,_))
             .WillByDefault(IncrementAndReturnPointee(&ret_value));
    }

private:
    ret_value;        
}
```

In the test, call:

```
TEST_F(TestSuite, TestScenario) {
    MockObject mocked_object;
    mocked_object.useAutoIncrement(0);

    // the rest of the test scenario
    ...
}
```