# Google Mock Return a live element using ON_CALL

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googlemock

I read through [Google Mock: Return() a list of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144623/google-mock-return-a-list-of-values) and found out how to return a single element from a vector on each EXPECT_CALL, as such I wrote the following code which works:

```
    {
      testing::InSequence s1;
        for (auto anElem:myVecCollection) {
          EXPECT_CALL(myMockInstance, execute())
              .WillOnce(testing::Return(anElem));
        }
    }
```

so far so good...
Now I read not to use EXPECT_CALL unless you need to. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/googlemock/pRyZwyWmrRE
My use case, myMockInstance is really a stub providing data to the SUT(software under test).

However, a simple EXPECT_CALL to ON_CALL replacement will not work(??), since ON_CALL with WillByDefault only calculates the return type only once(??)

As such I tried setting up an ACTION.

```
ACTION_P(IncrementAndReturnPointee, p)
{
    return (p)++;
}

ON_CALL(myMockInstance, execute())
        .WillByDefault(testing::Return
         (*(IncrementAndReturnPointee(myVecCollection.cbegin()))));
```

Clang gives

```
error: expected expression   'ACTION_P(IncrementAndReturnPointee, p)'
```

Then I tried setting up a functor and use the Invoke method on it.

```
    struct Funct
    {
      Funct() : i(0){}

      myClass mockFunc(std::vector<myClass>  &aVecOfMyclass)
      {
        return aVecOfMyclass[i++];
      }

      int i;
    };

    Funct functor;                
    ON_CALL(myMockInstance, execute())
        .WillByDefault(testing::Return(testing::Invoke(&functor, functor.mockFunc(myVecCollection))));
```

Clang gives

```
no matching function for call to 'ImplicitCast_'
        : value_(::testing::internal::ImplicitCast_<Result>(value)) {}
```

Now , I am fairly new to google-mock but have used google-test extensively. 
I am a bit lost with the Google-Mock doc. I wanted to know, whether I am on the right path, in terms of what I needed. 
If one of you could point to me , which approach is the correct one; or whether I am even close to the right approach, I can take it from there and debug the "close to right approach" further. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`testing::Return` is an action. Your code should look like:

```
ACTION_P(IncrementAndReturnPointee, p)
{
    return *(p++);
}

ON_CALL(myMockInstance, execute())
     .WillByDefault(IncrementAndReturnPointee(myVecCollection.cbegin()));
```

As a side note, it doesn't look like a good idea to use a finite collection `myVecCollection`. You will probably get a more robust test if you figure out an implementation of the action that creates a new element to return on the fly.

Comment: Thanks. Since , I am using gmock to create a stub, I already know what will be the inputs to my SUT , beforehand. However, for legacy code reasons, I cannot provide the elements on the fly everytime.